# Is there a way to change the splash screen color based on the Apps theme?

Tags: android, flutter, themes, splash-screen

Can the native android splash screen color be changed programmatically, so that it can be set fitting to the theme chosen for the Flutter app?

Kind of like how the WhatsApp splash screen loads in a dark theme when the System theme is set to dark.

Dark and light WhatsApp splash screen:

[image: Dark and light WhatsApp splash screen]

I guess this uses two themes for the splash screen, which are linked to the system theme, but I don't know that much about how and if that's possible.

So the question is: Is it possible to change the color/theme of the splash screen while running a flutter application, so that on the next start of the app the native android splash screen loads in the same theme as the Flutter app?

(Sorry if I repeated myself a lot, but I want to describe what I'm asking as good as possible)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your project folder's `android/app/src/main/res` there should be a `drawable` folder, which contains the `launch_background.xml` for light theme. Duplicate this folder and call the second one `drawable-night` and configure the dark theme style. It will automatically change based on Android's system theme.

The `launch_background.xml` in the `drawable` (light theme) folder can be structured as so, to display an image with a white background:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/launch_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The same can be done in the `launch_background.xml` in the `drawable-night` (dark theme) folder, replacing `"@android:color/white"` with `"@android:color/black"` for a black background.

Do note that the images must be inside of the `drawable` and `drawable-night` folders being used respectively. As far as I know, the format must be a png.

I found [this useful article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/splash-screens-for-dark-and-light-mode-in-flutter-eb85f1aa025) that addresses and explains native splash screen theming.

Comment: I originally wanted to change the splash screen based on the theme of the app alone (independent of the system theme) but it looks like that's not possible. This is the next best thing. Thank you!

Comment: would you mind sharing the code here instead of referring to an article? the link might get deleted in the future.

Comment: Done, I added the xml code as well as some essential information from the article.

Comment: Is there any way to change this based on user preference and not system setting? I'm new to android development, so asking

Comment: Flutter starts drawing after the android app is fully loaded in, so you won't be able to do that with Flutter, you'll have to use native code. You will likely have to store the user's preference on the device, and read it when the app starts up (and show the appropriate splash screen).

Comment: You can use a ternary operator in android xml (condition ? whatToDoIfTrue : whatToDoIfFalse) to decide the color.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the splash screen from the Android folder xml files, then i guess you can't escape writing some Native code and placing some of your theming logic in the Android subfolder. On the other hand, if the theming logic and splashscreen is both in the `main.dart` file. Then you can just store the two different **splashscreens** you want to use and add some **if-else** statement to display the splash screen and also save user theme preference. If you don't know how to do this, you can follow this thread: 
[How to load theme at beginning in fluttter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105320/how-to-load-theme-at-beginning-in-fluttter)

Comment: Yeah it would have to be some native stuff, as I want to use the native splash screen. Do you have any idea on how to do that or where I should look?

Answer (score -2):

You can use some sort of `SharedPreferences` to hold the current state of the Theme. Then return the desired theme to the `MaterialApp` based on the value saved in your `Shared Preferences`. I personally use `HydratedBloc` package to save the current states of my app, including Theme.

Comment: But the splash screen is shown before any Flutter code runs.

Comment: Hey the flutter app starts after android is loaded, your answer only tells how to enable the dark theme after flutter starts, doesn't answer the og question